# Is changing the value of a Map an atomic operation?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, dictionary, atomic

I was wondering if synchronization or using a concurrent class is necessary, or conversely is it thread safe to use a non concurrent class and do no synchronization on a map in a multi threaded environment, if the only modification to the map is changing the values of the map.

The reason I ask this is the HashMap ( and other non concurrent maps documentation ) have this comment:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized.
>   If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of
>   the threads modifies the map structurally, it *must* be
>   synchronized externally.  (A structural modification is any operation
>   that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value
>   associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a
>   structural modification.)  This is typically accomplished by
>   synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the map.

Which makes me believe if the modification is not structural (i.e. There is no  added or deleted) I should be able to update the (non concurrent) map sans synchronization.

Am I reading this correct? i.e. Is Updating of a value in a map an atomic process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating a map value is not an atomic process.  However, having multiple different threads each try to modify map values concurrently will not result in very strange exceptions or errors due to concurrency errors.  For example, you won't cause one of the key/value pairs to disappear, or delete random elements out of the map.

However, the updates made by one thread when updating a key/value pair will not necessarily be visible to other threads unless there is some other synchronization going on (for example, if the values are things like `AtomicIntegers`).  On top of this, there's no guarantee that the thread will even see its own updates, since they might get clobbered by some other thread.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You will get an inconsistent state of the `Map`, even though no exception is thrown on concurrent access, you will get crazy behavior when you rely on a value previously stored in a map.

Comment: @stryba- Can you elaborate on this?  What do you mean by "inconsistent state?"  My answer explicitly indicates that the writes might not be visible, but I'm pretty sure that you won't corrupt the map.  I could be wrong about this, so anything you can provide would be most appreciated.

Comment: with inconsistent I mean you will not know whether your key/value was actually stored in the map while another thread wrote to the very same map, where it doesn't matter whether they write to the same key. It is also not ensured that the same thread sees its own written values as you indicate.  BTW: -1 came not from me, I'd said so

Comment: I've seen an example where concurrent inserts to a HashMap actually broke things.  Where, yes, it *did* corrupt the collection, to the point where NullPointerExceptions were being thrown because a bucket went missing.  I'm trying to re-find it...but in the meantime, know that without synchronization, with a data structure as complex as a HashMap, you can't rely on anything to work.

Comment: @cHao - The key phrase in the documentation is "modifies the map *structurally*". Updating values is not a structural change; inserting and removing keys is. This was addressed by both the question and answer.

Comment: There are other problems related to the concurrent access of Map implementations. For example, threads may enter in a infinity loop due to references rearranging, as seen in http://mailinator.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Comment: @PEdroArthur- My answer is specifically about what happens when you modify *existing* values within a `map`, rather than when you have multiple concurrent reads and writes. Does the link you posted still apply in this case?

Comment: @templatetypedef mostly not. My point was to state that concurrency is subject to other implementation details and even to external ones such as volatility (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/), to list a few. Therefore, I think that a proper answer to this question would encompass guiding the OP to use more elaborated data structures such as the ones at java.util.concurrent.

Comment: @PEdroArthur- That makes sense. I'd interpreted the OP's question narrowly about updating values and not in a broader context, though I did mention issues about inter-thread visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Putting something in a `HashMap` is not an atomic operation:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

It may be worthwhile to wrap your `HashMap` with [`Collections#synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean here.  If the key/value pair already exists and the value is replaced, it seems like it would be atomic (though not necessarily visible by other threads).  The question specifically assumes that this doesn't cause a structural modification.  Does your answer still hold in this case?

Comment: For better performance with lots of reads you can use your own synchronization based on read/write lock pattern though.

Comment: @templatetypedef The operation of replacing the value is atomic, but the call to `put` is not. If you're using a `Map` in a concurrent environment, synchronization is never a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Implementations of map such as `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, etc are not atomic nor thread safe when it comes to updates, but you may achieve atomic update operations when you're using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) since Java 1.8.

The following method for example will add the value for a specific key or set the value if no previous value was available for the key.

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

int addValue(String key, int value) {
    return map.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? value : v + value);
}
```

Comment: Why did you say "since Java 1.8"? That class dates back to Java 1.5. The new 1.8 methods added seem to be all about lambda/streams, nothing to do with atomic updates. Atomic updates seems to be the original  *raison d’être* of this class, by my reading.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was referring to "Is Updating of a value in a map an atomic process", and put more weight to the value it self, since you needed more than 1 method to do the same operation before before Java 1.8. But yes, you're right about that the class has been around since Java 1.5 and is performing atomic updates. I've might have misread the question.